# How to truly open any website inside a single webpage?

Tags: javascript, iframe, proxy

I have been working on a digital platform that has the core idea of allowing users to open and access other websites all inside a single webpage. I have tried using iframe and probably most of the github public resources, but what I am trying to do has nothing to do with what I believe is commonly available online. I am searching for a system that allows my platform to create something similar to a browser tab, but inside a website, therefore it must allow the user to access every website without any type of block (such as what you get when trying to access Facebook through an Iframe), and also use the browser's cookies and cache that are saved to ensure a more fluid experience. I know that there are some ways of doing it through a permission given directly by the websites I am trying to access, but for this case I want to create a mechanism that allows that connection to happen in the same way that if it was done by a common browser (I am calling it a proto-browser so far).

What should I do to make this work? Should I create a proxy server for each user? How do I get a user to access Amazon and make a purchase or access Facebook and post something without them leaving the proto-browser?

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Answer: I don't think you can. Why? See below.

Most websites block framing to prevent an attack called clickjacking, which tricks the user into doing something harmless but is harmful. An example of what this is is shown below.

```js
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

function transparent() {
iframe.style.opacity = 0;
}

function opaque() {
iframe.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```css
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
margin: 0;
}

iframe {
border: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 2s;
}

.clickjack {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 140px;
}
```

```html
<p>In the example below, a fake button is underneath a link on a transparent Wikipedia iframe.</p>
<p>To see an example:</p>
<ol>
<li>Click "Opaque" to see the Wikipedia iframe. Notice that you're viewing the page called "Main Page".</li>
<li>Click "Transparent" to see the fake button.</li>
<li>Click the fake button.</li>
<li>Click "Opaque" to see the Wikipedia iframe.</li>
<li>Did you notice that the page has changed to "Contributions"? This is an example of clickjacking.</li>
</ol>
<button onclick="transparent();">Transparent</button>
<button onclick="opaque();">Opaque</button>
<div style="position:relative;height:200px">
<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"></iframe>
<button class="clickjack">Click here!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

If the `X-Frame-Options` or a Content Security Policy bans third-party sites from displaying content in a frame, then they are banned from doing so. It would be a pointless security feature if it could be overwritten by the third-party site.

If a browser blocks third-party cookies for privacy reasons, then a site can't overwrite that. It would be a pointless privacy feature if it could be disabled by a website.

If you implemented a reverse proxy to copy content from other sites on demand, then you wouldn't be able to read the cookies intended for the site you were proxying. It would be a major security problem if my browser send cookies connected with `http://mybank.com` to `http://yourproxy.com/mybank.com/`.

If you implemented a forward proxy, using SOCKS or similar, then you could do this … but it would require that everybody using the website would have to reconfigure their browser to use your proxy. This would give you access to all their HTTP requests and responses. That would be a major security problem.

---

If you want this level of access to what a user is doing on the Internet, then you need to write a browser not a website.

Comment: Take a look at the Browser UI dApp we've been implementing for GRIDNET OS https://gridnet.org  It consists of a 'hacked' iframe and a CORS mitigation reverse proxy.